# How to send a "password reset" email from Swift with Supabase?

Tags: swift, authentication, swiftui, supabase

I try to rest passwords for users in my swift application. I'm using Supabase as backend. How I can trigger the send?

In Java or Flutter it's like:

```
supabase.auth.resetPasswordForEmail(
  'sample@email.com')
```

But in swift I cannot select this option... Can someone help me?

```
supabase.auth.update(password: newPw)
```

I can update the password but can't send the email

Answer (score 0):

The [Gotrue-Swift](https://github.com/supabase-community/gotrue-swift) also has this [method](https://github.com/supabase-community/gotrue-swift/blob/main/Sources/GoTrue/GoTrueClient.swift#L329) to reset password for Email:

Here's the function prototype:

```
public func resetPasswordForEmail(
    _ email: String, redirectURL: URL? = nil, captchaToken: String? = nil
  )
```

So, you can call it:

```
resetPasswordForEmail('example@example.org')
```